# Opensource проекты для получения опыта

Tags: java

Здравствуйте.

Просматривая вакансии на Java программиста в интернете, можно заметить, что даже для джуниура почти везде нужно 1-2 года опыта работы.

Много раз читал, что для получения реального опыта программирования на Java можно принять участие в разработке какого-нибудь опенсорс проекта(забесплатно :D). Скажите пожалуйста, как найти такие проекты и предложить себя в качестве кандидатуры :)

В теории я уже достаточно хорошо разобрался : в Java SE и основах Java EE(Servlets, JSP, JSF), знаю основы SQL, HTML, CSS, JavaScript.

Comment: иди на собеседования, не флуди и не ной )

Comment: Вот кто мне нужен. Я работаю над сайтом wtruib.ru. Мне нужно разобраться с одним приложением и сделать подобное приложение для андроид.

[тут я разбираюсь как это сделать][1]

напиши мне на почту (см в профиле)


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/237857/java-%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83

Comment: > напиши мне на почту (см в профиле)

Ща заспамят :)

Comment: В общем то на собеседование в разные компании меня приглашают, но там полный 8-9 часовой рабочий день. Для меня как для студента(5 курс) такой вариант пока не подходит. А парт-тайм предложений я не нашел. Наверное плохо искал :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> даже для джуниура почти везде нужно 1-2 года опыта работы.

Это еще что. Мне попадались вакансии Senior Ruby Developer с 6+ годами опыта, хайлоадом и всем таким, **не старше** 23 лет. )

По сабжу. Если немного покурите Spring MVC, Hibernate и JQuery, то можете попробоваться на [один из проектов JTalks](http://jtalks.org/display/jtalks/JTalks+Home+Page). Ребята разрабатывают набор компонент для развертывания форумов/блогов/ всего такого с тесной взаимной интеграцией. Первый релиз уже состоялся и можно [посмотреть что получилось](http://javatalks.ru/), но работы еще много. Опыт командной разработки для новичка (да и не только) будет отличный.

Comment: > Это еще что. Мне попадались вакансии Senior Ruby Developer с 6+ годами опыта, хайлоадом и всем таким, не старше 23 лет. )

это нормально. Читал о том, что Гвидо (автору Питона) предлагали работу, зная что он разбирается в питоне (но не зная, что он его автор)  и назвали требуемый опыт работы больше, чем на тот момент существовал питон.

Comment: в общем-то, он был для них идеальным вариантом, хотя бы потому что опыт работы с Питоном у него действительно был явно больше, чем время существования самого языка)